# jQuery marquee cutting off text when giving the container 100% width

Tags: jquery, css, marquee

trying to create a looping marquee effect and came across this plugin:

```
https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee
```

Which actually does what I need, and simply because the content width will be changing by the user etc.

The issue is that when giving the container a 100% width the sliding content will just drop off / be hidden when it reaches the opposite side. If the container is e.g. 500px then it loops fine, but 100% width struggles.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jc7F3/1163/

You will see that the text is just dropping off on the right and no smoothly leaving the screen.

Any help?

```
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.sliding-marquee').marquee({
            duration: 10000,
            gap: 50,
            delayBeforeStart: 0,
            direction: 'right',
            duplicated: true
        });
    })
```

Comment: I didn't understand what your are saying because it looks like fine. Can you please explain it?

Comment: @sagarkodte when another  duplicate of the text is coming in on the left, its removing the first text part. So its only showing two parts of the text and removing the first when the next is coming into view. This causes it to just disappear instead of finishing the transition.